# Pivot table added to Google Sheets using API ignores color theme. How do I make it match the theme, like a manually added pivot table does?

Tags: java, google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-api

A **pivot table** added to a **Google Sheets** sheet via the **API** simply **appears in shades of grey only**, whereas one added manually uses the colors of active theme. **How can I make the pivot table added through the API behave like the manually added one?**

To observe the problem:

1. Add a pivot table to a Google Sheets sheet manually. Note that the pivot table is nicely colored according to the selected theme **(menu | Format | Theme)**.
2. Change the theme and note that the colors in the pivot table change to match it.
3. Add another pivot table, but this time using the API. Note that the pivot table appears in shades of grey, regardless of the theme.
4. Change the theme and note that the original (manually added) pivot table changes its colors to match but the programatically added pivot table stays grey.
5. This applies to copies of the pivot tables made using copy and paste, too.

Where is the property of the pivot table that makes it match the theme? Does it need to be registered somewhere as a "themed" component? Is this a bug with Google Sheets?

I am using the Java API. The payload used is as follows:

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateCells": {
        "fields": "*",
        "rows": [
          {
            "values": [
              {
                "pivotTable": {
                  "source": {
                    "endColumnIndex": 15,
                    "endRowIndex": 607,
                    "sheetId": 407627043,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                    "startRowIndex": 532
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "start": {
          "columnIndex": 4,
          "rowIndex": 8,
          "sheetId": 1176225417
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update:** I believe this is a bug and have filed an issue on Google's issue tracker. The URL of the issue is: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178201666

Comment: Can you plase share the payload used?

Comment: @JoseVasquez done.